# d3.js Force Directed Graph - Using Images instead of Circles for the Nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am trying to visualize a dynamic network topology by using d3.js. So far, I could make it work by putting circles as nodes, but I have to put different custom images for different node types.

My current code is like this:

```
 node = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(jsonTry.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .call(d3.drag()
        .subject(dragsubject)
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));
```

As a start, I wanted to put an image to all nodes to see how it works like the following:

```
node = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.data(graph.nodes)

node.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
.attr("x", -8)
.attr("y", -8)
.attr("width", 16)
.attr("height", 16);
```

It doesn't seem to be working this way since I can see just the links, and nodes just dissappeared. I found some examples using d3 v3, but currently I'm using d3 v4 and want to implement it accordingly (since I had problems with forceLink() not being included in v3)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach would work if you were appending the `<image>` to the `<g>`. However, you're appending the `<image>` to the `<circle>` element, and that won't work.

You have two solutions:

1. Append the `image` to the groups, not to the circles;
2. Keep your circles, but use a `def`:

   ```
   var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

   defs.append("svg:pattern")
       .attr("id", "myPattern")
       .attr("width", 1)
       .attr("height", 1)
       .append("svg:image")
       .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
       .attr("width", 16)
       .attr("height", 16)
       .attr("x", 0)
       .attr("y", 0);
   ```

Here is a demo:

```js
var nodes = [{
    "id": 1,
}, {
    "id": 2,
}, {
    "id": 3,
}, {
    "id": 4,
}, {
    "id": 5,
}, {
    "id": 6,
}, {
    "id": 7,
}, {
    "id": 8,
}];

var links = [{
    source: 1,
    target: 2
}, {
    source: 1,
    target: 3
}, {
    source: 1,
    target: 4
}, {
    source: 2,
    target: 5
}, {
    source: 2,
    target: 6
}, {
    source: 1,
    target: 7
}, {
    source: 7,
    target: 8
}];

var index = 10;
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    node,
    link;

var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

defs.append("svg:pattern")
    .attr("id", "myPattern")
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("height", 1)
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
        return d.id;
    }).distance(100))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(50))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
        return d.target.id;
    })

link = link.enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    })

node = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "url(#myPattern)")

simulation
    .nodes(nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
    .links(links);


function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
        });
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = undefined;
    d.fy = undefined;
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #aaa;
}

.node {
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using the second solution by adapting your demo code to my code. There doesn't seem to be any error on console, but this time nodes appear to be stacked in the left top corner of the screen. What can be the reason of this behavior?

Comment: And also if i want to put different images for different nodes, in your demo's case for different node id's, how can i give different URLs for different ids?

Comment: Since my demo works, your code has a *different* problem. In that case, I suggest you post another question, with the corresponding code (even if not working).

Comment: I finally made it work! I will post another question for putting different images for each node. Thank you!